# Blender is Lagging Suddenly

Tags: error, performance

I just started using blender yesterday. I have been following Blender Guru's donut tutorial, and I have gotten pretty far, but now when I try to sculpt, I can barely see the effect, and when I start using the mouse (I.E. clicking the left mouse key to execute the action of sculpting), the whole application just stops, for a few seconds. Literally, 2 hours ago, It was working fluidly, and now it is too laggy to effectively use. I have seen something about a opengl32.dll file being the problem, but when I searched the computer, I got like, 10 opengl32.dll files, and if I delete them all, it will effect my computer badly, since other applications use them too, and when I visit the blender file, I can't seem to find any opengl32.dll files. My computer has 32gb RAM, and it is only a month or two old, so I hardly think it is a computer issue. I even restarted & updated the computer, and the problem persists.

Like I said, just randomly started lagging, and I can't find anything to help. I also don't really know how to put the system info from blender in this post, as there is not a "file" option from what I can see, but when I searched the document with "ctrl + h" nothing regarding opengl32.dll showed up. I really need to continue learning blender, because I need to make assets for Unreal Engine 4. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, It turns out that due to a subdivision surface modifier, too many vertices were being made, and lagged out the application. By not applying the modifier, it stopped the lag.